# the component does not appear in the west border layout

Tags: java, swing, components, layout-manager, border-layout

I Have this code

```
package com.company;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Alarm extends JFrame {
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Java Alarm Clock");
JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

JMenu clock = new JMenu("Clock");
JMenu alarm = new JMenu("Alarm");
JMenu help = new JMenu("Help");

public Alarm() {
    super("Java Alarm Clock");
    getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(204,204,255));
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(770,470);
    setVisible(true);

    add(new pclock() , BorderLayout.WEST);

    add(menuBar , BorderLayout.NORTH);
    menuBar.setBackground(new Color(204,204,255));
    menuBar.add(clock);
    menuBar.add(alarm);
    menuBar.add(help);
}

class pclock extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        setBackground(new Color(204,204,255));
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillOval(40, 100, 180, 180);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Alarm();
    }
}
```

I want the output to be like this Pic
[image]

but when i run the code the circle does not appear 
it does appear only when i change this code

```
add(new pclock() , BorderLayout.WEST);
```

to

```
add(new pclock());
```

so how to make it appear in the left side like that picture ?
thank you

Comment: Can you show us what it currently looks like, i.e. the problem you're seeing?

Comment: `public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        setBackground(new Color(204,204,255));
        super.paintComponent(g);` The call to `setBackground(new Color(204,204,255));` should be in the constructor. It only needs to be done once, and we should not change the state of a component within a paint method as that will trigger a `repaint()`!

Comment: `setVisible(true);` should be the last method call in the `Alarm` constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Class names SHOULD start with an upper case character. You custom class is named incorrectly.
2. The WEST area of the BorderLayout will respect the width of any component added to it. Your custom component has a size of (0, 0) so there is nothing to display. You need to override the `getPreferredSize()` method of your custom class to return the size of the clock.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.